# Core Data images "unrecognised selector..."

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data, uiimage

I have a data model with an entity called Image.  This will be used to store images.

Previously I had the image as an attribute of a specific entity.

I set up the transformable stuff and it all worked.

However, now I've moved it into a separate entity I keep getting errors.

So...  This is the Image.m file contents.

```
#import "Image.h"
#import "Person.h"

@implementation ImageToDataTransformer


+ (BOOL)allowsReverseTransformation {
    return YES;
}

+ (Class)transformedValueClass {
    return [NSData class];
}


- (id)transformedValue:(id)value {
    NSData *data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(value);
    return data;
}


- (id)reverseTransformedValue:(id)value {
    return [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:value];
}

@end

@implementation Image

@dynamic image;
@dynamic createdDate;
@dynamic person;

@end
```

When I save it it doesn't complain when I create it it doesn't complain, I can even see it in the Person entity as an object.

```
(Person *) $0 = 0x1002dec0 <Person: 0x1002dec0> (entity: Person; id: 0x4f8f30 <x-coredata://2800C028-8745-45FE-854B-5783FF3FC173/Person/p6> ; data: {
    avatar = "0x1007e540 <x-coredata://2800C028-8745-45FE-854B-5783FF3FC173/Image/p1>";
    createdDate = nil;
    email = nil;
    firstname = Blah;
    id = "1234567890987654321234567890";
    lastName = Blah;
    updatedDate = nil;
})
```

The avatar attribute is a relationship to an Image entity (one to one).

But if I try to access any attribute of the image I get this...

```
-[_NSObjectID_64_2 createdDate]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1007e540
-[_NSObjectID_64_2 image]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1007e540
```

etc etc...

Code that generates error...

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestForEntityName:@"Person"];

[request setPredicate... blah];
NSArray *results = [context executeFetchRequest...];

Person *person = [results objectAtINdex:0];

NSLog(@"%@", person.firstName); //this works fine.
NSLog(@"%@", person.avatar.createdDate); //this crashes.
```

Tried removing the image attribute and still getting the same problem.

Comment: Where is the code that causes the error?

Comment: Now you can show us your data model)This may help too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, that was completely bizarre.

I deleted the entity and re-added it... still the same problem.

I deleted it again and added an entity called "StoredImage" instead of "Image" and it worked fine with no problems at all.

Thanks for all the help though.

Answer (score 1):

Given the type of crash you are generating, make sure you are assigning the proper class name while using the core date modeling tool. By default, it does not create the subclass with the entity name, and it leaves you to access the property values by using key-value coding. Go do your modeling tool, select the entity, and check the class name on the model data inspector on the utilities panel.

Comment: Ah, I thought you'd got it then but it was already populated properly.  I used the generator to create the subclasses so it was populated automatically.

Comment: The generator will generate the class file, but in the runtime, the class name will show as NSManagedObject. Check the class name on the model data inspector on your core data model. Alternatively, you can print the address pointed by the debugger. Should give you the class name of the record. If it's an NSManagedObject subclass, your class is not being generated correctly. If it's, then the problem is of a different nature.

Comment: actually, by looking at the crash, the problem is of a different nature. The runtime value of the class is _NSObjectID_64_2, which is NSManagedObjectID. Check your relationship configuration.

Comment: he annoying thing is that I have set up loads of relationships already through Core Data on this project and this is no different.  I've now removed the image attributed from the entity so all it has is a date and a relationship to Person.  Still the same problems.